# How do I save an Enum Case value to UserDefaults for further usage

Tags: swift, enums

How do I save the value of an enum case to `UserDefaults`? I have tried and had no luck. I checked multiple sites including this one, but with no luck, they all are in Swift 2 or in Objective-c which I can't translate at all.

Comment: It's more like you have an `ExampleEnum` with 3 values, then you need to persist, somehow, the selected value as the default.

Comment: Seems you have written an answer in the place of question. You usually cannot get up-voted for such wrong usage. Improve the question as meaningful with its own and write an answer as answer. I recommend you to hurry as wrong usage of this site is often down-voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**-UPDATE-**

figured It out for myself I had to add an integer extension to my enum case so the enum had a value to save

so I started with two global variables at the top of my file containing the switch method

```
var switchCurrentType = .default1
var currentDefaultType = UserDefaults().integer(forkey: "CurrentDefaultType")
```

then I declared the enum case in the file where I was switching the cases (like if you want to switch on the press of a button or in a didMoveToView method you put your case here)

```
enum ExampleEnum : Int {
    case default1
    case default2
}
```

then I use this when switching the case

```
switchCurrentType = .default1 //or whatever you are trying to switch to
```

and I use this to save it to UserDefaults

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(switchCurrentType.rawValue, forKey: "CurrentDefaultType")
```

here is reading the saved data for further usage

```
//in the didMoveToView method put this code in
switchCurrentType = ExampleEnum(rawValue: UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "CurrentDefaultType"))! //make sure exclamation mark at the end is there or it won't read properly
```

Answer (score 14):

Create the enum with a property list compliant raw value for example `Int`

```
enum ExampleEnum : Int {
    case default1
    case default2
    case default3   
}
```

Implicitly the first case is 0, the second is 1 and so on.

Now you can save the (raw) value in `UserDefaults`

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(currentDefaultType.rawValue, forKey:"Foo")
```

And read it back

```
currentDefaultType = ExampleEnum(rawValue: UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey:"Foo"))!
```

Comment: I implemented it but its giving me an error saying my cases aren't found in the ExampleEnum and I quote "Enum case 'default1'not found in type 'ExampleEnum'"

Comment: Please edit your question and add the affected code. My solution is supposed to work.

Comment: this is my way I'm changing the currentDefaultType first I declare this at the top of my viewController "var currentDefaultType = ExampleEnum(rawValue: UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Foo"))" then I switch it like this "currentDefaultType = .default1"

Comment: The code in the question doesn't compile anyway. You have to tell the compiler the type either `var currentDefaultType : ExampleEnum = .default1` or without annotation `var currentDefaultType =  ExampleEnum.default1`

Comment: let me try it hold on -EDIT- I changed my code above to include a custom function that seems to be working

Comment: but the switch method doesn't seem to be working let me edit my code above to include all my problems

Comment: There are many many typo errors in the edited code: After `integer(forKey:` the colon is missing. The type in the `button` method is `Any` (uppercase), in the same line the `{` is missing. In the next line the dot is missing (`.default1`). But the main issue is the missing `enum` declaration before `ExampleEnum` -> `enum ExampleEnum : Int {` And declare `currentDefaultType` non-optional by adding a `!` at the end of the line.

Comment: The `switch` statement must be in the same scope (controller) as the enum declaration.

Comment: still saying it can't find the type

Comment: The error occurs because `currentDefaultType` is optional. I already wrote: *And declare `currentDefaultType` non-optional by adding a `!` at the end of the line.*

Comment: what the heck is wrong with me that worked!!! I am such an idiot I do apologize if I caused you any trouble. thanks so much!!! you just laid some of the paving stones for my game