# Can a nested enum be saved inside UserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, nsuserdefaults

Let's say I have the following enums:

```
enum UserState {
    case LoggedIn(LoggedInState)
    case LoggedOut(LoggedOutState)
}

enum LoggedInState {
    case Playing
    case Paused
    case Stopped
}

enum LoggedOutState {
    case Unregistered
    case Registered
}
```

Is there a way to save `UserState` to `UserDefaults` ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441946/how-do-i-save-an-enum-case-value-to-userdefaults-for-further-usage) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes

You can use [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) protocol to transform your enum into a representation that can be saved in UserDefaults. This [tutorial](https://medium.com/@hllmandel/codable-enum-with-associated-values-swift-4-e7d75d6f4370) might give you a kickstart.