# How to save an enum conforming to Codable protocol to UserDefaults?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, codable

Follow up from my previously [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358141/how-to-use-codable-protocol-for-an-enum-with-other-enum-as-associated-value-nes):

I managed to make my enum to conform to Codable protocol, implemented init() and encode() and it seems to work.

```
enum UserState {
    case LoggedIn(LoggedInState)
    case LoggedOut(LoggedOutState)
}

enum LoggedInState: String {
    case playing
    case paused
    case stopped
}

enum LoggedOutState: String {
    case Unregistered
    case Registered
}

extension UserState: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case loggedIn
        case loggedOut
    }

    enum CodingError: Error {
        case decoding(String)

    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let loggedIn = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .loggedIn) {
            self = .LoggedIn(LoggedInState(rawValue: loggedIn)!)
        }
        else if let loggedOut = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .loggedOut) {
            self = .LoggedOut(LoggedOutState(rawValue: loggedOut)!)
        }
        else {
            throw CodingError.decoding("Decoding failed")
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        switch self {
        case let .LoggedIn(value):
            try container.encode(value.rawValue, forKey: .loggedIn)
        case let .LoggedOut(value):
            try container.encode(value.rawValue, forKey: .loggedOut)
        }
    }
}



class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let state = UserState.LoggedIn(.playing)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(state, forKey: "state")
    }
}
```

My problem is I don't know how to save it to UserDefaults. If I just save it like I do now I get the following error when running the app:

```
[User Defaults] Attempt to set a non-property-list object Codable.UserState.LoggedIn(Codable.LoggedInState.playing) as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key state
2018-01-20 19:06:26.909349+0200 Codable[6291:789687]
```

Comment: What is `encoded` in the above example?

Comment: Sorry, it should have been state there. Type issue.

Comment: @Kobe: note the code change I made in your question. The decoder threw an error no matter what.

Comment: Note that when parsing JSON using Decodable protocol you can throw DecodingError instead of creating your own error type. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46458771/2303865

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `UserDefaults` reference:

> A default object must be a property list—that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections, a combination of instances of) **NSData**, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of NSData.

So you should encode `state` manually and store it as data:

```
if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(state) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "state")
}
```

Then, to read it back:

```
guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "state") else { fatalError() }
if let saved = try? JSONDecoder().decode(UserState.self, from: data) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Don’t use value(forKey:) UserDefaults has specific method to load data type values in this case data(forKey:) and consequently no need to conditionally cast from `Any?` to `Data`, all you need is to unwrap its value. `guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "state")  else {`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks. I totally forgot about those specific methods, I updated the answer.

Comment: @LeoDabus That's up to OP (maybe the `UserState` value is bound to an `UISwitch` state) In any case it is immaterial to my answer and more relevant as comment in the original question, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4+**. **Enum** with a **normal** **case**, and a **case** with **associated** **value**.

1. **Enum**'s code:

```swift
enum Enumeration: Codable {
    case one
    case two(Int)

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case one
        case two
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        if let value = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .one), value == "one" {
            self = .one
            return
        }

        if let value = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .two) {
            self = .two(value)
            return
        }

        throw _DecodingError.couldNotDecode
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        switch self {
        case .one:
            try container.encode("one", forKey: .one)
        case .two(let number):
            try container.encode(number, forKey: .two)
        }
    }
}
```

2. **Write** to UserDefaults:

```swift
let one1 = Enumeration.two(442)

if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(one1) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "savedEnumValue")
}
```

3. **Read** from UserDefaults:

```swift
if let savedData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedEnumValue") as? Data {
    if let loadedValue = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Enumeration.self, from: savedData) {
        print(loadedValue) // prints: "two(442)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enum should have rawValue to have ability to be saved as Codable object. Your enum cases have associated values, so they cannot have rawValue.

[Article with good explanation](https://medium.com/@PhiJay/why-swift-enums-with-associated-values-cannot-have-a-raw-value-21e41d5ec11)

**My explanation**

Lets imagine that you can save your object `.LoggedIn(.playing)` to UserDefaults. You want to save `UserState`'s `.LoggedIn` case. There are 2 main questions:

1. What should be saved to the storage? Your enum case does not have any value, there is nothing to save. You may think that it has associated value, it can be saved to the storage. So the 2nd question.
2. (imagine that you saved it to storage) After you get saved value from storage, how are you going to determine what the case is it? You may think that it can be determined by the type of associated value, but what if you have lots of cases with the same associated value types? So the compiler does, it does not know what to do in this situation.

**Your problem**

You are trying to save the enum's case itself, but the saving to the UserDefaults does not convert your object by default. You can try to encode your `.LoggedIn` case to `Data` and then save the resulting data to UserDefaults. When you will need to get saved value you will get the data from storage and decode the enum's case from the data.